# How to solve bundle(not loaded) issue in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, osx-mavericks

```
2014-01-21 10:27:42.248 app[19510:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x8ca29a0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
```

I am getting above error in debug area of Xcode 5 in Mavericks! I tried 'Reset content and Settings' option too. Though there are many threads regarding this issue, none of them have exact solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found your post when searching for a solution.  My application appeared to be running fine but I was still getting this message  I was able to eliminate the message on my machine, here is what I had to do;

Stop all execution on the simulator.

Go to the simulator's home screen using shift-command-h.

Delete the app from the simulator device by holding a click on my program until the delete icon appeared, then click the X to delete.

In the iOS Simulator select Reset Content and Settings.

Clean the project in Xcode, shift-command-k.

Build it and run it.

Note, I was doing steps 4 & 5 but that wasn't working.  It wasn't until I added step 3 (as crazy as it sounds) that it cleared my message.

Hope this works for you!

if the reset of the simulator does not solve your problem try the following:

In Terminal type:

open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs
Delete your "iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk". Then reinstall Xcode. Reinstalling is really fast because just the missing folder gets replaced. This fixed it for me.

for more check this link-> https://devforums.apple.com/message/925386#925386

Comment: @RodBarnes  - Check your build settings. It's likely you only have armv7s listed as supported
architectures. Modify the settings so it includes armv7 and the error should be
corrected.  On your second issue, sorry, no idea. Looks like you're using features
but not including the required frameworks in your app.

Comment: @Vizllx - Architectures list "arm64 armv7 armv7s"

Answer (score 0):

iOS Simulator > Reset content and settings...

It helped me with this problem!